# Transpose values from txt to spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

Case:

```
Public Sub Example1()

'dialog result
Dim intDialogResult As Integer

'path selected by user
Dim strPath As String

'single line of data from the text file
Dim strLine As String

'string seperated by the delmiter
Dim arrString() As String

'curren row in excel sheet
Dim i As Integer

Dim FileName As String

'disallow user from selecting multiple files
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False

'remove previous filters
Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Clear

'display the open file dialog
intDialogResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

'if the user selected a file
If intDialogResult <> 0 Then

'path selected by the user
strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

'close the file index #1 if its already opened
Close #1

'open the file for reading
Open strPath For Input As #1


i = 1
'loop while the end of file has not been reached

While EOF(1) = False
    'read one line of data from the text file

    Line Input #1, strLine

    'split string based on delimiter
    arrString = Split(strLine, " ")

    'I only need the 6th column values
    ActiveCell(i, 2) = arrString(6)
    i = i + 1

Wend
End If
Close #1

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate

End Sub
```

Basically what it does is it takes values from 6th column from a .txt file and puts them next to each other each time the macro runs.

Problem 1: I want to store them horizontally (up to 200 values in each column from .txt file)

Problem 2: I want to set the first cell as the file name

Comment: if you copy the data in excel, while pasting, you should see an option for transpose.

Comment: What language or application are you trying to do this in? Transpose is a bit of a vague term.

Comment: Excl VBA. I want the cell(X,Y) from one sheet to become cell(Y,X) on the other sheet.

Comment: And I'll need a macro. 200 x over 5000 cells to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with shortcut keys. If you want to see the code, turn on Record Macro:

On sheet 1:

select any cell within your array
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`a` <-select all
    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`c` <- copy

Move to sheet 2:

select cell A1
    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+`v` <- Paste Special
   `e` <- Transpose
    <kbd>Enter</kbd> <- Paste

Comment: And it gives me the error "we can't paset because the Copy area and paste area aren't the same size"

Answer (score 0):

To fill data across columns instead of down the rows, you can change

`ActiveCell(i, 2) = arrString(6)`

to

`ActiveCell(1, i) = arrString(6)`.

To extract the filename from StrPath use

`FileName = StrReverse(Left(StrReverse(strPath), InStr(1, StrReverse(strPath), Application.PathSeparator) - 1))`

(you declared `FileName as String` but didn't use it)

To place `FileName` on the first cell just add `ActiveCell = FileName` at the line just before entering the `While` loop, and set `i` to start from 2 (i.e. `i = 2`)

For the part concerned, the whole changes would look like (comments removed):

```
FileName = StrReverse(Left(StrReverse(strPath), InStr(1, StrReverse(strPath), Application.PathSeparator) - 1))
ActiveCell = FileName

i = 2
While EOF(1) = False
    Line Input #1, strLine
    arrString = Split(strLine, " ")
    ActiveCell(1, i) = arrString(6)
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

And finally, if my wild guess is right, to activate the first cell on the next row, use

`ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate`

Comment: weird...I tried and it always returns on the first line each time I add a new .txt file but the filename and transpose works!